# Multisite Global Custom Posts

Tags: custom-post-types, multisite, globals

I have a museum client with a multisite setup with pages that detail the exhibits in their facility. They recently added tablets throughout the museum and want their tablets to display only their exhibits (no other extraneous pages from the main site) for visitors to use while in venue.

I thought the solution would be a separate site on their network. However, I don't want them to have to update their exhibits in two different places.

So my question: Is it possible to do a global custom post from the parent website that also displays on a specific child site? And will the custom posts sync for all updates and changes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case anyone comes across this question in the future, I found a plugin that does everything I want.

The plugin is [Multisite Post Duplicator](https://wordpress.org/plugins/multisite-post-duplicator/) which is a free plugin available in the Wordpress plugin directory. Below are some of the plugin features.

Features:

- Copies all custom fields
- Copies all related post meta
- Includes any custom post type on your network as long as the post type exists  in your destination site
- Automatically copy your post/page/custom post type from one site to another from within your workflow
- Copies any featured image (Can be turned on or off in Settings)
- Copies all image media within post content to the new site's media library for exclusive use in the destination site (Can be turned on or off in Settings)
- Copies associated tags (Can be turned on or off in Settings)
- Batch Duplication
- Settings page to customise the default behaviour
- Restrict functionality to only certain sites on your network
- Clean and friendly User Interface
- Select what status you want your new copy of post to be i.e Published, Draft etc
- Specify a prefix for the new post to avoid confusion
- Works with Contact Form 7
- Works with Advanced Custom Fields